# What's a good way to visualize a tree-like data structure in .NET (in real time if possible)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, tree

I'm working on an algorithm that creates a tree-based data structure, and I'd like to visualize how the tree looks. Is there's [graphviz with .dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)), but that doesn't feel like a good solution if I want to see how the structure changes as the program runs, and would also require an external program (graphviz) to generate the images.

Is there some .NET library for either WinForms or WPF that I can feed my tree data and have it draw & layout the tree automatically?

Alternatively, is there a simple algorithm for generic tree layout (without a fixed branching factor), so that I could write this myself using WPF/Winforms?

Comment: You can try this library: https://github.com/panthernet/GraphX (has nuget package also). If you clone their git repo, there is sample WPF application where you can see how it works. Also would be good if you provide some requirements (how often data changes\should be redrawn, how many items in the tree expected and so on).

Answer (score 1):

One way I do this is to add a self-hosted WebAPI API onto the app that can supply the graph data and then create a small static HTML website that calls that API and renders the graph using D3.JS and Webcola.

There are simply more and better libraries for graph rendering in JS than in .NET.

See http://blog.abodit.com/2014/11/home-automation-systems-graph/

Comment: You can as well just use web browser control for that, not?

Comment: @Evk Yes, you could host it in a web browser control, good point. My 'app' is typically an NT Service but for a client-side app, a hosted browser control could work well.